# ¿Para que sirve git revert HEAD~5..HEAD~3?

Tags: git, github

Hasta ahora se que se puede usar git revert con un solo commit; Ejemplo: git revert HEAD~1

Pero, ¿que pasa si pongo otro commit? Ejemplo: git revert (commit 1)..(commit 3)

Comment: No te estás devolviendo en el tiempo. Estás revirtiendo los cambios que hicieron esos commit, creando nuevos commit con la reversión de esos cambios

Comment: si, lo se, lo que no entiendo muy bien es que sucede si lo hago con dos commits. ¿Se fusionan ambos para asi crear uno nuevo?

Comment: No, se crean dos nuevas revisiones que van a revertir los cambios primero de `HEAD~3` y luego la de `HEAD~4`

Answer (score 0):

**Siempre y cuando no haya operaciones merge** y estés trabajando sobre esa rama sin conflictos, inicialmente cada commit en el revert va en un nuevo commit.

Ya si usas `--no-commit`, te acumula cambios hasta que haces un commit.

```
$ git revert --no-commit D
$ git revert --no-commit C
$ git revert --no-commit B
$ git commit -m "One commit to push them all"
```

También se puede definir un rango de commits en el HEAD, por ejemplo

`git revert --no-commit HEAD~3..`

Revirtiendo los últimos 3 con un único commit, creando un rango al usar `..` (`HEAD~3` equivale a `HEAD~3..HEAD`).

Hay más detalles en la [documentación](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) y en [este hilo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463340/how-to-revert-multiple-git-commits) en SO original.